# DirectX 9 HLSL SSAO?

Tags: c++, shader, ssao

I need a DX9 HLSL SSAO shader, but I have only limited knowledge of shaders. I'm trying to learn so that I can write one, but it's a steep curve.

I don't understand most of the theory of SSAO, so any in-depth explanations would be great.

While I don't *need* code to understand theory, usually I learn best by reading through real code (even if it's just short pieces of code).

Bearing that in mind, my question is this: How do I do SSAO, using DirectX 9?

Comment: If you don't know much about shaders, why are you jumping in at the deep end?

Comment: Because I have to. I need an SSAO shader and I don't understand how SSAO works. Actually, it's not so much the shader syntax itself that I don't understand, it's what goes on to create the AO effect...the maths, if you will. I'm currently trying to convert a DX10 SSAO shader back to DX9; this shader http://www.justinmclaine.com/shader---ssao.html